# Convert year, month and day to single date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

The ruby method

DateTime.new(@year, @month, @day)

uses three integers `@year` `@month` and `@day` to create a single datetime.

Is there a jQuery method that accomplishes this?

Comment: @developerbmw Yeah I tried earlier but there's that stupid waiting period haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't a jQuery method for this but you can do it with pure JS.

`var date = new Date(2015, 9, 28);`

**Note:** For this particular example months are 0-based, so the 9 in the example above means October.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date